# merge multiple tables (belonging to group 'x')

Tags: sql, pivot

I have three tables in the database:

customer -table

- customername
- customerid

group -table

- groupid
- groupname

customer-group table

- customerid
- groupid

What kind of SQL generates the output:
customername, 'X' if the customer belongs to a group 1, 'X' if customer belongs to a group 2, ...
(Group number is limited to 7.)

For example:

```
Matt, 'X', '' , 'X', '' , 'x', '' , ''
Mark, '' , 'X', '' , 'X', '' , 'X', ''
```

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

In the code below I am joining the main table which is the `customer` with the navigation table `customer-group` multiple times once for each possible group.

Since I am using left joins, I am ensuring the the left part each time will always be returned and the if the right part does not exist then it will be returned as a null value

```
select 
customername,
case when cg1.groupid is null then '' else 'X' end as 'ExistsInGroup1',
case when cg2.groupid is null then '' else 'X' end as 'ExistsInGroup2',
case when cg3.groupid is null then '' else 'X' end as 'ExistsInGroup3',
case when cg4.groupid is null then '' else 'X' end as 'ExistsInGroup4',
case when cg5.groupid is null then '' else 'X' end as 'ExistsInGroup5',
case when cg6.groupid is null then '' else 'X' end as 'ExistsInGroup6',
case when cg7.groupid is null then '' else 'X' end as 'ExistsInGroup7'
from customer c
left join [customer-group] cg1
    on c.customerid = cg.customerid
    and groupid = 1
left join [customer-group] cg2
    on c.customerid = cg.customerid
    and groupid = 2
left join [customer-group] cg3
    on c.customerid = cg.customerid
    and groupid = 3
left join [customer-group] cg4
    on c.customerid = cg.customerid
    and groupid = 4
left join [customer-group] cg5
    on c.customerid = cg.customerid
    and groupid = 5
left join [customer-group] cg6
    on c.customerid = cg.customerid
    and groupid = 6
left join [customer-group] cg7
    on c.customerid = cg.customerid
    and groupid = 7
```

As many problems in the world this is also able to be solved with many different approaches. For instance you could use many subqueries for each field like so:

```
select 
customername,
case when exists (select top 1 1 from [customer-group] cg where c.customerid = cg.customerid and groupid = 1) then 1 else 0 end as 'ExistsInGroup1',
case when exists (select top 1 1 from [customer-group] cg where c.customerid = cg.customerid and groupid = 2) then 1 else 0 end as 'ExistsInGroup2',
case when exists (select top 1 1 from [customer-group] cg where c.customerid = cg.customerid and groupid = 3) then 1 else 0 end as 'ExistsInGroup3',
case when exists (select top 1 1 from [customer-group] cg where c.customerid = cg.customerid and groupid = 4) then 1 else 0 end as 'ExistsInGroup4',
case when exists (select top 1 1 from [customer-group] cg where c.customerid = cg.customerid and groupid = 5) then 1 else 0 end as 'ExistsInGroup5',
case when exists (select top 1 1 from [customer-group] cg where c.customerid = cg.customerid and groupid = 6) then 1 else 0 end as 'ExistsInGroup6',
case when exists (select top 1 1 from [customer-group] cg where c.customerid = cg.customerid and groupid = 7) then 1 else 0 end as 'ExistsInGroup7'
from customer c
```

Another example of a solution would be to utilize a pivot. A bit more advanced case. You may check documentation for SqlServer PIVOT [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select c.customername,
    max(case when cg.groupid = 1 then 'X' end) has_grp1,
    max(case when cg.groupid = 2 then 'X' end) has_grp2,
    max(case when cg.groupid = 3 then 'X' end) has_grp3,
    max(case when cg.groupid = 4 then 'X' end) has_grp4,
    max(case when cg.groupid = 5 then 'X' end) has_grp5,
    max(case when cg.groupid = 6 then 'X' end) has_grp6,
    max(case when cg.groupid = 7 then 'X' end) has_grp7
from customer c
inner join customer_group cg on cg.customerid = c.customerid
group by c.customerid, c.customername
```

Notes:

- You did not tell which database you are running; the above query uses standard `case` expressions, that (almost) all databases support. Your database may have neater alternatives though
- It does not look like we need table `group` to generate the desired result; if that's needed for some reason (say you want to pivot over the group name rather than over the group id), you can just add another join to the query

Answer (score -1):

```
select c.customername,
iif(g.groupname=1, 'x', ''),
iif(g.groupname=2, 'x', ''),
iif(g.groupname=3, 'x', '')  -- etc etc

from Customer c inner join customer-Group cg on c.customerid = cg.customerid
inner join group g on cg.groupid=g.groupid
```

Comment: `iif` function is not supported in all the database engines, consider not only adding a note to the answer warning about it but also giving aliases to the columns